# JQuery Post to php with dynamicaly created IDs

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I am trying to create a method that posts data to mysql when called. The only problem is I can't figure out how to pass it the correct information from the fields as their IDs are created at runtime.

The fields are created using a while loop and on double click they become editable then on blur they are supposed to revert to their previous state and post any changes made to the database.
(this is my first time writing one of these I hope I'm clear!)

My JS

```
function disablefarm(farmid) {
  $(function() {
    var farmstr = farmid.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""),
      farmID = $("#farm" + farmstr + "").val(),
      farmName = $("#farmn" + farmstr + "").val(),
      fieldarray = $([]).add(farmName).add(farmID);
    $("input:text[id=" + farmid + "]").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
    $("input:text[id=" + farmid + "]").addClass("noshow");
    var epost_url = "editfarm.php";
    var epost_data = fieldarray.serialize();
    $.post(epost_url, epost_data, function(response) {
      alert(response);
    });
  });
}
```

The html elements are created in a while loop that outputs

```
echo "<td name='farmL' ><input type='hidden' value='$id' id='farm$id' />   <input type='text' id='farmn$id' value='$fname' readonly='readonly' class='noshow' size='33' ondblclick='enablefarm(this.id)' onblur='disablefarm(this.id)' />";
```

And finally editfarm.php looks like

```
if (filled_out($_POST)){
    $efarmID = check_input  ($_POST['farmID']);
    $efarmName = check_input  ($_POST['farmName']);
}
else{           
    echo "not committed";       
}

$query = "UPDATE farm_name
          SET farmName='".$efarmName."' 
          WHERE farmID=".$efarmID.";";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
{   
    echo"".stripslashes($efarmName)." not updated";}
else{
    echo"".stripslashes($efarmName)." updated"; 
}
```

The HTML output looks like this

```
<tr id='row27'>
    <td name='farmL'>
        <input type='hidden' value='27' id='farmid27' />
        <input type='text'
               id='farmn27'
               value='111 Gary farms'
               readonly='readonly'
               class='noshow'
               size='33'
               ondblclick='enablefarm(this.id)'
               onblur='disablefarm(this.id)' />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding a document.ready handler *inside* a function (using `$(function() {...})`)? That way I don't think it'll ever get called.

Comment: It is managing to get the values correctly, I can alert and get the name and ID if I want them so it is doing something. I probably need a better way to do it though. I can't figure out how to pass the information about which field was clicked easily to the method.

Comment: Also, as for why, I.. erm.. couldn't think of a better way to do it mostly, if there is one please let me know!

Comment: To help us answer your question, can you show us the resultant HTML, rather than the PHP that generates it. (For example, the entire table as it appears in your browser.)

Comment: Thanks, I've put the HTML that the while outputs at the end, hope that helps!

Comment: The issue I'm having is either with creating the array or where it is serialized. It doesn't want to take the data from the HTML and is therefore not posting anything, the php should work.

Comment: Did you see how I passed the data to `$.post()` in my answer? You don't need to create an array and then serialize it when you can just pass it as an object directly. (PS: If you have a comment about the answer, please add it to the answer rather than the original question.)

Comment: I thought I had added it to the answer. And, yes I think I get the idea about how to post it properly now! Please forgive my lackluster skills, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing js to minimum, I would have done this by introducing an extra attribute to your dynamically generating inputs.

`<td><input type="text"
           data-id="27"
           name="farmid27" 
           value="111 Gary Farms"
           class="farmEdit" /></td>`

Now simply update your js to:

```
$(document).on("blur", "input.farmEdit", function() {                
            $.post("editfarm.php",    
            {
                farmID : $(this).attr('data-id'),
                farmName : $(this).val()
            },
            function(response) {
                alert(response);
            });
    });
```

Here you can see the 'data-id' attribute removed the dependency on input name, and I would suggest why to introduce input name when you are posting it individually using ajax(atleast for these types of cases).

Comment: But I don't want the inputs to be editable by default, I was hoping to have them become editable on one function and then revert and post on another. The ability to edit the attributes is restricted to admins so my theory was that I would gate the function behind this check and by default the inputs remain uneditable (the plot thickens). That's why they defaulted to readonly. Thanks for the answer, it seems to work well.

Comment: A combination of elements from both answers work best, I wish I could select both of them!

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier if you refactor your code somewhat. If you modify your PHP code to output the table content to look something like this:

```
<td>
    <input type="text"
           name="farmid27"
           value="111 Gary Farms"
           class="farmEdit" />
</td>
```

(The indentation is just to make it readable.)

Then you can rewrite your JavaScript to something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("blur", "input.farmEdit", function() {
        var $inputElement = $(this),
            inputName = $inputElement.attr("name"),
            inputValue = $inputElement.attr("value")
            curFarmId = inputName.substr(6); // Strip off the "farmid.." prefix

        $.post(
            "editfarm.php",
            {
                farmID : curFarmId,
                farmName : inputValue
            },
            function(response) {
                alert(response);
            });
    });
});
```

This takes advantage of jQuery delegated events and the fact that the `this` object in a click handler refers to the page element that was clicked (the `<input>` in this case).

Comment: Thank you so much! That is much cleaner than my method (and working). Though I was trying to make it post on blur rather than on click. My theory was I could doubleclick the form to make it editable, I have a method that removes readonly and the css from it, and then when I click out of the box it posts any changes I have made.

Comment: @a_programmer - Yeah, I bound the event handler to "click" instead of "blur" by mistake. I've updated my post to show what I *meant* to do :-) If you find an answer to your question, please 'accept' it by clicking the tick.